# Adding delay to Javascript function call by calling python script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've looked into a great deal of solutions which make use of `setInterval` and `setTimeout`, however I thought I could give it a go adding a delay between function calls with use of a python script.

To explain the code:

- I have a dropdown menu which contains the football matches being played today. When a user selects an option from this dropdown list i.e. it detects a `change`, then it executes a bunch of code to update the page with the relevant information.
- Within this function I have another function `liveCommentaryCall()`
  which uses AJAX to get the latest updates in the football match selected from the dropdown menu.
- Of course I need to call this every X seconds to update the webpage
  regarding the latest events.
- At the end of the function I make an AJAX `POST` request to a
  specific URL `/delayRequest`, which I then have that route in flask
  simply perform a `sleep()`and return.
- After this I then call the function `liveCommentaryCall()`again to
  restart the update procedure.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#teamDropdownSelector").change(function(){
    .
    .
    .
    function liveCommentaryCall(){ 
            alert("called");
            .
            . // bunch of code to update the page
            .
            $.ajax({
                url: "/delayRequest",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(""),
                success: function(response) {
                alert("RESPONSE RECIEVED");
                },
                error: function(delayError) {
                    alert("Something's gone wrong!");
                }
            });
            liveCommentaryCall();
        }
    //Now out of the function scope. 
    //Below is the first time the liveCommentaryCall function gets called.
    liveCommentaryCall();
});
```

**PYTHON**

```
@app.route("/delayRequest", methods=['POST', 'GET'])  
def delay():  
    time.sleep(10)  
    return;
```

However, opposed to calling the function, it running, then having a delay of 10 seconds before being called again, the webpage just peppers me with "called" alerts, meaning `liveCommentaryCall` is just getting called instantly on loop somewhere?

I can't see anywhere in code which should be causing this, which makes me think theres some underlying principle I'm overlooking.

**Question**
Is the error in the fact that I cant use a python script like this, or am I just not coding this idea correctly?

Comment: because you are not calling the function inside the success handler.... You basically wrote this:  `function liveCommentaryCall() { liveCommentaryCall(); }`

Comment: @epascarello Surely that doesn't matter? It needs to complete that AJAX request first (which takes 5 seconds) and then should move onto the call underneath it? To clarify, the code I've omitted is pretty heavy duty and takes about 8 seconds to fully execute before even reaching this last AJAX call. But at the moment "called" is being printed instantly, meaning its not even executing the whole function before being called again.

Comment: That is NOT how asynchronous calls work. Basically you call the server and it just keeps moving on.

Comment: It completes the AJAX request. The **A** stands for asynchronous, so it makes a call and continues in the main loop, the request will be handled separately

Comment: Also, even *if* you disable the asynchronous behaviour, that's NOT a good idea, since while the code is waiting 10s for the call to return, *no other JS would run on the page*.

Comment: Also not sure why you would want to do this in the first place.  Holding http requests open for 10 seconds to sleep seems weird.

Comment: Ah, thats embarassing. Apologies guys. Tired minds aren't the best coders I guess. Pretty rookie mistake. Appreciate the help regardless, if either vlaz or epa want to put their comment as an answer I'll choose as solution

Comment: @epascarello My first ajax request goes to a python script which scrapes a webpage and returns the data. the python script doing so requires selenium as the data I'm scraping is loaded by JS. So I have to wait until the webpage is loaded before I can scrape it. TL;DR - To scrape data I need my python script to open the url using selenium, which takes 4-5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `liveCommentaryCall` recursively, you can use the `setInterval` function in the `script`:

```
<script>
  setInterval("liveCommentaryCall()",1000); //call every second
  function liveCommentaryCall(){ 
        .
        . // bunch of code to update the page
        .
        $.ajax({
            url: "/delayRequest",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(""),
            success: function(response) {
            alert("RESPONSE RECIEVED");
            },
            error: function(delayError) {
                alert("Something's gone wrong!");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wasn't me, though I'd guess it was perhaps that I'd mentioned I'd looked into setInterval and setTimeout solutions and wanted to try it this way? Regardless I do appreciate the help :)